# How can I ignore first results from a function in Lua?

Tags: function, lua, multiple-results

Lua functions can return multiple results :

```
a, b, c = unpack({'one', 'two', 'three'})
```

If I'm not interested in the third return value, I can choose to ignore it when calling the function :

```
a, b = unpack({'one', 'two', 'three'})
```

Is there a similar way to ignore the X first elements when calling the function ?

I could write this code if I only want the third return value, but I was wondering if a cleaner code exists :

```
_, _, c = unpack({'one', 'two', 'three'})
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [`select`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-select) function. It will return all arguments after `index`, where `index` is the first argument given to `select`.

Examples:

```
c = select(3, unpack({'one', 'two', 'three'}))
b, c = select(2, unpack({'one', 'two', 'three'}))
b = select(2, unpack({'one', 'two', 'three'}))   --discard last return value
```

That said, I think in most cases, writing `_,_,c = f()` is cleaner. `select` is mostly useful when the argument number is not known in advance, or when chaining function calls together (e.g. `f(select(2, g()))`)